# Problems with gelatine

Tags: gelatin

got the following recipe from a UK newspaper.  Tried it and it did not set.  At all!  My gelatine was fresh and 200-225 bloom and the grapefruit juice was freshly pressed.  It tasted delicious but we had to drink it!  Contacted the food and drink department of the newspaper but just got waffle as a reply.  Tried it again with double the gelatine but it still didn't set fully and had a slightly different taste.  Has anyone got any ideas please?

4 sheets gelatine, 
400ml pink grapefruit juice, 
150ml Campari, 
2 tablespoons sugar.
Normal method of soaking gelatine and adding to slightly warmed juice.

Comment: It's possible that the fresh squeezed is the problem.  There are a number of fruits that can only be used canned or heat pasteurized, or enzymes in them break down the gelatin.  I wasn't aware of grapefruit being a problem, but oranges are often listed as the 'slight problem', and it's possible that juice (rather than whole fruit) makes the problem worse.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/33957/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47450/67

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll try that.  Might try heating the fresh grapefruit juice first and if that doesn't work will try bought grapefruit juice.  And if that doesn't work either I'll just have to skip the gelatin and drink it!

Comment: There is a reason that there is no grapefruit gelatin mix on the market. Grapefruit prevents setting, and alcohol just makes the problem worse. It may be worth the effort to see if you can find grapefruit ester for the jelly instead of using the juice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using 3 things that are enemies of gelatin:

- Acids
- Enzymes
- Alcohol

These 3 things are very common protein denaturant agents, which means that they break down the protein structure. And well, gelatin is a protein, so adding freshly pressed grapefruit juice (acid + enzymes) and alcohol to gelatin will prevent it from setting.

You should boil well the mixture of sugar, juice and alcohol before using and rectify volume with water.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I hadn't tried the recipe again because of the problems I'd encountered.  Will give your recommendations a go and see if I have success without compromising the flavour.